# Take away role after a given interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
 setTimeout(() => {
            targets.forEach(target => target.roles.remove(arole));
            message.channel.send(`Removed ${arole}`);

        }, RoleTime);
    }
}
```

I use the above snippet to take away the roles of mentioned users after mentioned time. It works perfectly (I use ms to store RoleTime in milis). But when the time is like 12h the bot doesn't seem to reply and take away the role(Hosted on Heroku). Any idea why? What are the other ways to achieve this?

Comment: You should use cron job for a process like this.

Comment: Im not sure how do it in heroku, but in other platforms like GCP you call web service https or create cloud function for call in certain time your process

Comment: My guess is that your dyno is stoping. It is not the correct approach for such a delay as the other comments suggest

Comment: I tried cron. Read a lot of docs too. But couldn't out how to.

Comment: What else can I do? Cron? How?

Comment: @Anush You need to keep your Dyno online.

Comment: I my web Dyno every 5 minutes. It doesn't sleep. By the issue prevails.

Comment: It may be safer to use [`cron` on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and save all the jobs in a database.